# Magento 1 - Is it safety to use Store Code in URLs?

Tags: magento-1.9, language, base-url

I need a multi language store using domain.com/fr/ domain.com/it etc structure (are more than 10 stores so domain.en domain.fr domain.it etc is not possible)

i can apply it in Configuration > Web > Url options >  Add Store Code to Urls

But Is it safety to use Store Code in URLs?

Magento alert is:
Warning! When using Store Code in URLs, in some cases system may not work properly if URLs without Store Codes are specified in the third party services (e.g. PayPal etc.).